# DataFactory Concat single quote

Tags: sql, select, azure-data-factory

Im trying to use ADF dynamic content with concat and I want to add a single quote around my date; CAST('2014-02-42') and that using inside of it item activity.output that contais data row timestamp. How to do that?

```
@concat('

DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128) = ''mydata.dbo.''
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(128) = ''MYTABLE''

SELECT ''select '' + @s + '' from '' + @schema + @tablename + '' WHERE TIMESTAMP < CAST('' + ''', activity('RetunedDate').output.runOutput ,''' + '' as Date)'' as Query
')
```

current result

```
select columns from mydata.dbo.mytable WHERE TIMESTAMP < CAST(2022-09-01 16:16:09.077000 as Date)
```

expected result

```
select columns from mydata.dbo.mytable WHERE TIMESTAMP < CAST('2022-09-01 16:16:09.077000' as Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below dynamic expression in the ADF dynamic content which will give you the desired result.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128) = 'mydata.dbo.'
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(128) = 'MYTABLE'

select @s from @schema+@tablename WHERE TIMESTAMP < CAST('@{activity('RetunedDate').output.runOutput}' as Date)
```

Use the String interpolation in ADF dynamic content for the Date.

Here is the sample query I got as input for activity, when I used above dynamic content. Here I don't used any sql database thats why I got error in the script but for you the above dynamic content will work.

[image]

You can see the single quotes before the date.